# Does a gRPC and Kubernetes connection only dial to one replica?

Tags: kubernetes, rpc, grpc

I have been studying gRPC and Kubernetes with Go. In my golang code, my API Gateway dials my micro services in a init() function before main begins.  My Question is if I have multiple replicas of my micro services and my API Gateway dials a one-time connection to the micro service does it stay connected to the first pod/replica that the load-balancer sends that traffic to? If not how does a load balancer keep that dialed connection active? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a load balancer in gRPC-Go, the load balancer tells gRPC which backends it should stay connected to, and for each request, which one to use.  For example, the [RoundRobin balancer](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#RoundRobin) will attempt to stay connected to every backend returned by the resolver, and rotate through all of the ones that were successfully connected.

[This doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md) covers the high-level basics of load balancing in gRPC if you would like more information.